# Basic question on union bound for high probability bound for martingale difference sequence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, martingales, concentration-of-measure

I have two martingale difference sequences $X_i$ and $Y_i$ with $|X_i| \leq 2H$ and $|Y_i| \leq 2H$. Then by Azuma Hoeffding inequality, I can say with probability at least $1-\delta/2$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^T X_i \leq \sqrt{2HT\log(2/\delta)}$$

Similarly with probability at least $1-\delta/2$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^T Y_i \leq \sqrt{2HT\log(2/\delta)}$$

By union bound can I say the following?

With probability at least $1-\delta$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^T X_i + \sum_{i=1}^T Y_i \leq 2\sqrt{2HT\log(2/\delta)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(X > c) \le \delta/2$ and $P(Y > c) \le \delta / 2$ then
$$P(X+Y > 2c) \le P(X > c \text{ or } Y > c) \le P(X>c) + P(Y>c) \le \delta.$$